# How do I switch party members?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I accidentally took Durance the Priest whom I met in forest instead of Sagani  the Ranger Dwarf girl and I don't want Durance in my team, I want the Ranger, how do I change my party?

I checked absolutely everything and I can't find an option to get her back into the party, all I found is that I can send her to complete missions from the stronghold but I don't want to do that.

So how can I switch my active party members?

Comment: I'd actually recommend a Priest over a Ranger, but that's me.

Answer (score 5):

I know of two ways in which you can exchange party members.

While in a tavern, if you talk to the innkeep about either rooms, hiring adventurers, or what goods they are selling you will open a dialog with four options down the left side. Selecting the bottom one, Party Management, will allow you to switch who is in your party.

You will also be shown the party management screen when you leave the grounds of your stronghold (not entering the buildings, but actually returning to your travels).

Comment: It might be worth to add, that while somewhere on Stronghold grounds you can open stronghold management and freely change party composition on the bottom tab.